# Xt error: Can't open display!

Tags: ubuntu, xterm

I am trying to run xterm on my Virtualbox ubuntu VM, but when I run xterm on the VM, I keep getting the message

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display!: 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

When I run xterm through putty (with X11 enabled) (from my host to the VM), I get:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: mininet-vm:10.0
```

Some of the outputs of the ssh config files:

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no    

cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep X
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Echo Displays:
On Putty:

```
echo $DISPLAY
mininet-vm:10.0
```

On the Virtualbox VM:

```
echo $DISPLAY
##blank##
```

Version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.10, Quantal Quetzal"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu quantal (12.10)"
VERSION_ID="12.10"
```

Comment: If you are running "PuTTY", it sounds as if your local machine is Windows.  There are no details about an X server on the local machine in your question.  People usually use Cygwin or something like that to provide X, and there are pages which tell how to tie those together.

Comment: yes, but even when I run xterm within the virtualbox console itself, i still get th emessage cannot find display

Comment: It sounds like you've installed a console-only ("server") version of Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, updated the question with the full version information

Comment: We can not tell from the version if it has X11. But do not worry. Ubuntu and Debian have many variants (steeldriver used the word version to describe this. This is correct, but ambiguous). Each variant differs only in what software is installed by default. Therefore it is possible to change variant by installing extra software. As  icespiker said you can add the minimal X11 by typing this into the command line `sudo apt-get install xorg`. You may also want to consider gnome, kde, fvwm or a different window-managment-system to go on top of X11.

Comment: Unfortunately, when running the `apt-get update` and then the `sudo apt-get install xorg` commands, I get the error `404 Not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at **Xming**, which provides the X window display server on your Windows host (you could also use Cygwin, for some it might be preferable).

Comment: You do not need X11 server on the remote end. Only on the local end. But you will need the X11 clients (eg xterm).

Comment: Also consider `vnc`.

Comment: @richard Thank you for correcting my answer. I would too recommend vnc. `tigervnc` is my favorite implementation, and it's frequently updated (also has Windows binaries).

Comment: I should maybe add that, as the protocol vnc uses is pixel based, a display server such as X is mandatory on the vncserver host (which, in OP's case would be his guest system).

Comment: The issue is that, from my own Ubuntu VM, when I enter the xterm command, I get an error. So dies this not mean the issue is on the VM and not on the host (windows) machine? When I ssh to my own VM, from my VM (so from Ubuntu, ssh to my own Ubuntu VM) and run xterm, I get an error.

Comment: **xterm** is a program meant to be run inside the X window system. You need to install the xorg server on your VM.

Comment: ... when you have installed it you'll be able to run software in a window system there _locally_ (and you'll then satisfy the main requirement to install window managers or desktop environments such as Gnome, KDE, dwm, i3 etc..).
You can install the Xorg server by typing:
`sudo apt-get install xorg`.
On the winhost side, Putty does not come with an X window display server, which is why I suggested you take a look at Cygwin or Xming. 
Your last comment is very confusing. Can you provide more concise information and be more clear on what machines you're running and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately, when running the `apt-get update` and then the `sudo apt-get install xorg` commands, I get the error `404 Not found`

Comment: Installed Xming and ran Putty with X11 forwarding again. It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## ssh scenario

You need to enable X11 forwarding in the ssh client (putty), and have X11 installed and running on the local machine. The machine name in the `DISPLAY` variable will not be the local machine, but something like `:10` ( a local (from the point of view of the remote machine) connection ).

## Direct use VM display

You need X11 running on the machine. If you just have a screen of text, no windows, no graphics, sometimes some colour, then you are not running X11, you can check using `ps` command.

We cannot tell from the version if it has X11. But do not worry. Ubuntu and Debian have many variants (steeldriver used the word version to describe this. This is correct, but ambiguous). Each variant differs only in what software is installed by default. Therefore it is possible to change variant by installing extra software.

As icespiker said you can add the minimal X11 by typing this into the command line: `sudo apt-get install xorg`.

You may also want to use gnome, kde, fvwm or a different window-managment-system to go on top of X11.

Comment: I did enable X11 on Putty when I initiated the ssh session, however it still did not work. However when you say X11 has to be installed and running on the local machine (assuming this is the host machine (my PC)), is it not installed by default with Putty? I checked the enable X11 when initiating the session.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I have been searching for hours and trying different suggestions.  I had the same problem, but on FreeBSD in a VirtualBox machine.  It was all about the missing xorg package.  Thank you once again.